# Trigger events with JS generated input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When using `onclick` or `onkeypress`, **how can I pass a variable as parameter from a button such as below**?

I am trying to prepend rows into an HTML table with jquery. The prepended row should be able to delete/edit said row but the `id` of the element cannot trigger the event. What is the best way to do this?

```
var myBtn = '<button type="button" id="btn_save">save</button>';
```

Call a function `onclick` of `btn_save` or `onkeypress` of a textbox and maybe pass `anotherVal` as parameter.

Comment: can you show your click handler?

Comment: you tagged javascript and jquery so how can we help you? provide your js code

Comment: if you don't have an answer by 8am est tomorrow I will provide one. I don't have the code and can't remember how I do it, but I have it at another location. I will post here when I get it. Sorry I can't be of help tonight.

Comment: I don't understand one part however..... what are you trying to target with the variable??

Comment: I did not post my js code since it's not working and I wasn't sure which way to put it. I'm just wondering if there is a way to call a function and pass a variable as parameter by clicking a button such as above. Thanks.

Comment: `<button type="button" onclick="someFunction('parameter')">save</button>'`or you may pass the whole element by `onclick="someFunction(this)"`

Comment: I think you want something like this:
`$("button").click(function(this) { $(this).parent().remove(); });`

Comment: @R Lam thanks but the first example returns an error, the second one return the element but when I use `onkeypress` for a textbox while passing `this`, the value is always the original value?

Comment: @esandrkwn Is this what you want? [https://jsfiddle.net/pw23hfvg/](https://jsfiddle.net/pw23hfvg/)

Comment: i'm sort of lost about what should be happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can bind the `click` event using jQuery's `.on()` event handler like:

```
$('body').on('click', '#btn_save', function(){
    console.log('function');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Now any element with id `#btn_save` created dynamically, will have this `click` handler bound to it.

https://jsfiddle.net/8ydL8jeL/

Comment: ...and listen for `keydown` events on textual input elements.